# Sort array of objects based on the ordered list of values

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const arr = [
{Id:"3",name: "ADMIN"},
{Id:"1",name: "SECURITY"},
{Id:"2",name: "INFORMATION_REPORTING"},
{Id: "23",name: "PAYMENTS_SERVICES"},
{Id: "344",name: "PAYMENT_HUB"},
{Id: "31",name: "RTP"},
{Id: "43",name: "PAYMENTS"},
{Id: "34",name: "GPI_ALERTS"},
{Id: "65",name: "ADMINISTRATION"}
]
```

I have the arr which has the values as describing here.And I want to reorder the arr using the key name as below, Order to be shown.

```
ADMIN
ADMINISTRATION
PAYMENTS
RTP
PAYMENTS_SERVICES
INFORMATION_REPORTING
PAYMENT_HUB
SECURITY
GPI_ALERTS
```

So I want the arr in this order shown above based on name key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `Array.prototype.sort()` and compare `arr` items based on their position (`Array.prototype.indexOf()`) within `orderList`

```js
const arr = [{Id:"3",name:"ADMIN"},{Id:"1",name:"SECURITY"},{Id:"2",name:"INFORMATION_REPORTING"},{Id:"23",name:"PAYMENTS_SERVICES"},{Id:"344",name:"PAYMENT_HUB"},{Id:"31",name:"RTP"},{Id:"43",name:"PAYMENTS"},{Id:"34",name:"GPI_ALERTS"},{Id:"65",name:"ADMINISTRATION"}],

    orderList =  ['ADMIN','ADMINISTRATION','PAYMENTS','RTP','PAYMENTS_SERVICES','INFORMATION_REPORTING','PAYMENT_HUB','SECURITY','GPI_ALERTS'],
    
    result = arr.sort(({name:nameA},{name:nameB}) =>
        !orderList.includes(nameA) ?
        1 :
        !orderList.includes(nameB) ?
        -1 :
        orderList.indexOf(nameA) - orderList.indexOf(nameB)
      )
      
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```